# Is it legit to ask one or two off-topic questions on comment of any post?

Tags: discussion, comments

Assume that, there is a question posted,
I saw someone who has commented on that post,
I visited his profile,
I wondered about something,
I want to ask him something,
I can't find him on any of the chat rooms. The post (where I saw him commenting) is the only place to get in touch with him.

So, my question is, Can I post one or two off-topic comments on any threat to ask a user something?

For example, I saw a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) related question, where a user answered that question very brilliantly, And I just wanted to ask him that "What are the good resource to learn regex" or "From where you learned Regex?". Now, if I ask right in the comment section to his answer, then my comments will be off-topic. *It is just an example, but the real case can be anything*.

So, should I ask off-topic questions in comments?

Comment: No. You say it yourself; the comments are off-topic.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from doing so - but it is not encouraged and likely to get deleted if someone flags.  But there is a whole regex chat room, why do you need the advise of that specific user.  There are dozens and dozens of RegEx experts around, so you are actually better off asking a group of experts than a specific one.

Comment: Related (and a better approach): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users

Comment: I greatly detest such comments.  But the only thing I can do about them is not answer them.  Well, and put your name in my little black book.  Avoid being a nuisance.

Comment: Each tag, including the [tag:regex] tag, has an [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) which answers your “where to learn” question.

Comment: Be careful with "any *threat* to ask a user " :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on the "Add comment" and you get the following placeholder text.

> Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid answering questions in comments.

You're doing neither of these things so your comment would just be noise and flagged as such.